# Utilizar get_object_vars em uma classe filha

Tags: php, funções, herança

Tenho a seguite classe:

```
class Dominio {

    private $teste;

    public function getAtributos() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

E outras classes que herdam ela(Dominio):

```
class ClasseQualquer extends Dominio {
    private $outro;
}
```

Eu instancio a classe 'ClasseQualquer' e chamo o metodo 'getAtributos':

```
$classeQualquer = new ClasseQualquer();
var_export($classeQualquer->getAtributos());
```

Então ele retorna o atributo 'teste' da classe 'Dominio', mas o que eu preciso é pegar os atributos da classe filha no caso 'ClasseQualquer' e pegar o atributo 'outro'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que resolveu para mim foi utilizar traits, um recurso muito interessante que não sabia que existia no php, mas obrigado pela força Wellingthon!

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.traits.php

Criei o arquivo:

```
<?php

namespace model\dominio;

/**
 * Description of traitDominio
 *
 * @author wictor
 */
trait traitDominio {

    public function getAtributos() {
        return array_keys(get_object_vars($this));
    }

}
```

E então importei nas minhas classes:

```
<?php

namespace model\dominio;

/**
 * Description of Token
 *
 * @author Wictor
 */
class ClasseQualquer extends Dominio {

    use traitDominio;
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Você definiu as variáveis `$teste` e `$outro` como sendo privadas ( *Private* ), ou seja, não podemos acessar a partir de outras classes descendentes.

Para que o método funcione como desejado, você deve defini-las como protegidas ( *Protected* ), somente assim elas poderão ser acessadas dentro da própria classe ou a partir de classes descendentes (herdadas).

```
class Dominio {

    protected $teste = 'Variável teste';
    public function getAtributos() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }

}

class ClasseQualquer extends Dominio {
    protected $outro = 'Variável outra';
}

$classeQualquer = new ClasseQualquer();
var_export($classeQualquer->getAtributos());
```

> Podes ver funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/NW3y/0)